# Unable to set profile picture using Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update my profile picture using Microsoft Graph Explorer (v1.0) but I'm unable to do it, I'm always getting the following error :

> An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., The file you chose isn't an image. Please choose a different file.

The problem is that the file I'm trying to update my picture with *is* an image inserted in the request body (a base64 representation of it, I used this site in order to get it: https://www.base64-image.de/).

I'm also using the header `Content-Type` with the value `image/jpeg` and I think that, as I'm logged, I don't need the authorization header.
The URL I'm using is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint takes the raw image as input, not a base64 encoded version. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update):

> #### Request body
>
> In the request body, include the binary data of the photo in the request body.

Since it isn't possible to stream a file like this using Graph Explorer, updating the photo isn't supported by Graph Explorer.